# Manipulating Pandas data frame to get into long? format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a df that looks like this:

| Year | code | Country | Quan1jan | Quan2jan | Quan1feb | Quan2feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 08123 | Japan | 500 | 26 | 400 | 28 |
| 2020 | 08123 | Taiwan | 450 | 245 | 4500 | 87 |

And I would like for it to look like this:

| Year | month | code | Country | Quan1 | Quan2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | jan | 08123 | Japan | 500 | 26 |
| 2020 | feb | 08123 | Japan | 400 | 28 |
| 2020 | jan | 08123 | Taiwan | 450 | 245 |
| 2020 | feb | 08123 | Taiwan | 4500 | 87 |

It doesn’t matter if the data follows this same order, but I need it to be in this format.

Ive tried to play around with melt, and unstack with no luck. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
pd.wide_to_long(
  df, 
  ['Quan1', 'Quan2'], 
  i=['Year', 'code', 'Country'], 
  j='month', 
  suffix='\w+'
).reset_index()

#   Year  code Country month  Quan1  Quan2
#0  2020  8123   Japan   jan    500     26
#1  2020  8123   Japan   feb    400     28
#2  2020  8123  Taiwan   jan    450    245
#3  2020  8123  Taiwan   feb   4500     87
```